# Как поделить несколько столбцов на один

Tags: python, pandas

Подскажите, сломал уже всю голову, не пойму как написать цикл, который поделит значения всех столбцов на один (последний). Есть df в нем 12 столбцов, нужно каждый (кроме последнего) поделить на последний. Вручную понимаю, что можно сделать так:
df["столбец1"] = df["столбец1"] / df["последний_столбец"]. Но таких таблиц 3 и заниматься копипастой не правильный все таки метод.

Comment: Вы не могли бы объяснить, почему из двух представленных ответов вы выбрали худший?

Comment: @strawdog кажись,  я просто позже написал, чем ответ был принят :)

Comment: Да, мне тот метод помог и я его сразу отметил, а уже позже я зашел и увидел другое решение моего вопроса

Answer (score -1, accepted):

что-нибудь такое может?

```
# Import pandas package 
import pandas as pd

last_col="последний_столбец"
# iterating the columns
for col in df.columns:
    if col != last_col:
       df[col] = df[col] / df[last_col]
```

P.S. в режиме отладки посмотреть правильно ли отрабатывается условие col != last_col

Comment: Да, спасибо большое!

Comment: Так можно, но циклы в `Pandas` лучше не использовать, если можно обойтись без них. А в данном случае - вполне можно.

Answer (score 3):

Можно поделить через метод [`div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) с указанием оси, и обойтись без циклов

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4], 'c': [5, 6]})

   a  b  c
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6

df[df.columns[:-1]] = df[df.columns[:-1]].div(df[df.columns[-1]], axis=0)

          a         b  c
0  0.200000  0.600000  5
1  0.333333  0.666667  6
```

или

```
df.iloc[:, :-1] = df.iloc[:, :-1].div(df.iloc[:, -1], axis=0)

          a         b  c
0  0.200000  0.600000  5
1  0.333333  0.666667  6
```

Comment: Я уже применил метод, который предложил "Vlad Chapl", он работает. Но не подскажете почему лучше не использовать циклы и чем они плохи? И так же я пока не очень хорошо разбираюсь в коде и ваше решение не понимаю: df[df.columns[:-1]] = df[df.columns[:-1]].div(df[df.columns[-1]], axis=0) т.е. мы к нашему df (кроме последнего столбца) применяем: делим все столбцы (опять же кроме последнего) на все столбцы? Буду благодарен за объяснение

Comment: делим все столбцы (опять же кроме последнего) на *последний столбец*

Comment: А циклы ,по крайней мере, замедляют выполнение кода, теряя все преимущества pandas. Ну а принятый ответ заминусовали наверное еще из-за странных формулировок про "последний столбец"

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!